# An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant when trying to convert java enum

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I tried to convert a java file to kotlin file but i'm getting this error : An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant

```
@StringDef(
    BillingEnum.ALL,
    BillingEnum.PAID,
    BillingEnum.PENDING,
    BillingEnum.OVERDUE,
    BillingEnum.OPEN,
    BillingEnum.DELETED
)
annotation class BillingEnum {
    companion object {
        var ALL = ""
        var PAID = "paid"
        var PENDING = "pending"
        var OVERDUE = "overdue"
        var OPEN = "open"
        var DELETED = "deleted"
    }
}
```

Before it looked like this:

```
@StringDef({
        BillingEnum.ALL,
        BillingEnum.PAID,
        BillingEnum.PENDING,
        BillingEnum.OVERDUE,
        BillingEnum.OPEN,
        BillingEnum.DELETED
})
public @interface BillingEnum {
    String ALL = "";
    String PAID = "paid";
    String PENDING = "pending";
    String OVERDUE = "overdue";
    String OPEN = "open";
    String DELETED = "deleted";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must write

```
annotation class BillingEnum {
    companion object {
        const val ALL = ""
        const val PAID = "paid"
        const val PENDING = "pending"
        const val OVERDUE = "overdue"
        const val OPEN = "open"
        const val DELETED = "deleted"
    }
}
```